# Improving PowerShell function

Tags: powershell

I have a function:

```
function LocateIP ([String] $IPPool, [String] $IP) {
    return $IPPool.contains($IP)
}
```

where $IPPool would be a file with lots of ips and $IP would be, of course, the IP.
function need to return true if $ip is inside the ippool.

This works great, problem arise when when i try to iterate a file of ips and then work line by line and running LocateIP function on it.

if the file holds more than 50k of ips and i do iterate line by line and checking, that could take lots of time, and, of course, more than that it gets much worse.

can i find another way that will help me to work with bigger files?

Comment: $ippool is nothing more than a parameter/variable that is explicitly cast to a single string, not a file. You need to show your actual code and problem you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine there are plenty of ways to speed it up:

1. Switch from `ForEach-Object { }` to `foreach() { }`
2. Don't call a PowerShell function for every line. Instead of calling LocateIP, run the `$line.contains($ip)` test directly. PowerShell function calls have a lot of overhead.
3. Avoid using `Get-Content` to read the file, when you could use `[System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines()` instead.
4. Push all the work down to a faster cmdlet such as `Select-String -Pattern ([regex]::Escape($IP)) -Path file.txt`
5. IP addresses form a tree structure; if you need to load the file once then do lots of checks, you could make a structure with faster lookup performance.

Comment: Those are some awsome tips. thank you